# JavaScript: How to update the values of a nested array (linter throwing 'no-param-reassign' warning)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array that looks like this:

```
const MENUS_LIST: MenuListing[] = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Analytics',
    defaultPath: '/analytics/sales/overview',
    relatedPath: ['/analytics/sales/overview', '/analytics/sales/bookings'],
    submenu: [
      {
        label: 'Overview',
        path: '/analytics/sales/overview',
        relatedPath: ['/analytics/sales/overview'],
        additionalIcon: [],
        name: ['Overview'],
        id: 'sales-overview',
      },
      {
        label: 'Bookings',
        path: '/analytics/sales/bookings',
        relatedPath: ['/analytics/sales/bookings'],
        additionalIcon: [],
        name: ['Bookings'],
        id: 'sales-bookings',
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

I need to convert it to the following format - by adding the `isActive` flag to the main structure and `submenu` when the current `path` === `submenu.path`.
In the following example, we assume `path` to be `/analytics/sales/overview`.

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Analytics',
    defaultPath: '/analytics/sales/overview',
    relatedPath: ['/analytics/sales/overview', '/analytics/sales/bookings'],
    isActive: true,
    submenu: [
      {
        label: 'Overview',
        path: '/analytics/sales/overview',
        relatedPath: ['/analytics/sales/overview'],
        additionalIcon: [],
        name: ['Overview'],
        id: 'sales-overview',
        isActive: true,
      },
      {
        label: 'Bookings',
        path: '/analytics/sales/bookings',
        relatedPath: ['/analytics/sales/bookings'],
        additionalIcon: [],
        name: ['Bookings'],
        id: 'sales-bookings',
        isActive: false,
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

I have the following solution which works (code is simplified):

```
  menuX = (MENUS_LIST as MenuListingProps[]).map((m: MenuListingProps) => {
    const resultX = { ...m };
    resultX.isActive = true; // will perform checking to determine true or false
    (m.submenu as MenuItemProps[]).forEach((sm: MenuItemProps) => {
      sm.isActive = true; // linter warning; value assigned based on checking (can be true or false)
      sm.icon = 'abc'; // linter warning
      sm.title = 'xyz'; // linter warning
    });
    return resultX;
  });
```

But the linter is complaining of `Assignment to property of function parameter "sm"` on the lines where I'm assigning values to `sm`

Based on this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62443942/assignment-to-property-of-function-parameter-no-param-reassign), I understand that I need to `copy the argument to a temporary variable and work on it instead`.

I did this by creating a new var `resultX`. But I'm not sure how to go about doing the same with `sm`.

Seeking some guidance, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
menuX = (MENUS_LIST as MenuListingProps[]).map((m: MenuListingProps) => {
    const resultX = { ...m };
    resultX.isActive = true; // will perform checking to determine true or false
    resultX.submenu = (m.submenu as MenuItemProps[]).map((sm: MenuItemProps) => {
      const sub = {...sm};
      sub.isActive = true; // linter warning; value assigned based on checking (can be true or false)
      sub.icon = 'abc'; // linter warning
      sub.title = 'xyz'; // linter warning
      return sub;
    });
    return resultX;
  });
```

Comment: I've tried this but it doesn't work. The new values assigned to `sub` are not getting updated to `menuX`.

Comment: I think this answer is correct now that @Amir made the edit.  It's not a very good answer, as it is devoid of any explanatory text.  The OP code was assigning the array from the inner loop to the function parameter on the outer map (which lint wants to treat as immutable).  In Amir's edit, the code only assigns to the mutable copies of the loop params

Comment: Thank you, it works. I missed this crucial part `resultX.submenu = `

Answer (score 1):

Here's a method using [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

[`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) doesn't mutate the original object, so it returns a new object with the given changes.

```js
const MENUS_LIST = [{"id":1,"name":"Analytics","defaultPath":"/analytics/sales/overview","relatedPath":["/analytics/sales/overview","/analytics/sales/bookings"],"submenu":[{"label":"Overview","path":"/analytics/sales/overview","relatedPath":["/analytics/sales/overview"],"additionalIcon":[],"name":["Overview"],"id":"sales-overview"},{"label":"Bookings","path":"/analytics/sales/bookings","relatedPath":["/analytics/sales/bookings"],"additionalIcon":[],"name":["Bookings"],"id":"sales-bookings"}]}];

const menuX = MENUS_LIST.map(menu => Object.assign(menu, {
  isActive: true, // will perform checking to determine true or false
  submenu: menu.submenu.map(submenu => Object.assign(submenu, {
    isActive: true, // will perform checking to determine true or false
    icon: 'abc', // linter warning
    title: 'xyz' // linter warning
  }))
}));

console.log(menuX);
```

Comment: Thank you, this works as well. Do you think that it's beneficial not to mutate the original object? I'm implementing this in React. Thinking of moving `menuX` to state.

Comment: Using React, yeah I'll sat its beneficial especially when you're using `setState` since it helps React know what exactly changed @yogesnsamy

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code helping you

```
var array = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Analytics',
    defaultPath: '/analytics/sales/overview',
    relatedPath: ['/analytics/sales/overview', '/analytics/sales/bookings'],
    isActive: true,
    submenu: [
      {
        label: 'Overview',
        path: '/analytics/sales/overview',
        relatedPath: ['/analytics/sales/overview'],
        additionalIcon: [],
        name: ['Overview'],
        id: 'sales-overview',
        isActive: true,
      },
      {
        label: 'Bookings',
        path: '/analytics/sales/bookings',
        relatedPath: ['/analytics/sales/bookings'],
        additionalIcon: [],
        name: ['Bookings'],
        id: 'sales-bookings',
        isActive: false,
      },
    ],
  },
];
array.map(o=>o.submenu.map(v=> o.defaultPath == v.path? {...v,isActive:true,icon:"abc",title:'xyz'}:{...v,isActive:false,icon:"abc",title:'xyz'}))
```

Comment: I would also need to update the `isActive` field which is outside of the `submenu`. How can I do it with your method?

Comment: if you want update isActive field which is outside of the submenu
you can do this.
array.map(o=>({...o, isActive: false}))